# Drupal + Mailchimp API : create campaign with an existing template

Tags: php, drupal-7, mailchimp

I'm trying to create a campaign with the Mailchimp PHP API in a custom Drupal module, but i fail to use an existing template.

I am sure of my template id in the request, but the id is always 0 in the response.

What is the correct request payload to reuse a template ?

I just want to reuse a very simple template. For now, there's no specific text for the campaign, i'll try to insert a text pattern when i'll be able to use the correct template.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my current code :

```
function mymodule_templates_list()
{
    $mailchimpPath = realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../libraries/mailchimp');
    require_once $mailchimpPath . '/src/Mailchimp.php';
    require_once $mailchimpPath . '/src/Mailchimp/Templates.php';

    $mailchimp        = new Mailchimp('my-api-key');
    $templatesService = new Mailchimp_Templates($mailchimp);

    $list = $templatesService->getList(
        array(
            'user'    => true,
            'gallery' => false,
            'base'    => false,
        ),
        array(
            'include_drag_and_drop' => true,
        )
    );
    dpm($list); // just to verify the template ID

    $campaignService = new Mailchimp_Campaigns($mailchimp);

    $response = $campaignService->getList();
    dpm($response);

    $options         = array(
        "list_id"     => 'my-list-id',            // this is OK, correct list used in the response
        "subject"     => "My subject",            // OK
        "from_email"  => "mymail@dev.null",       // OK
        "from_name"   => "Site name",             // OK
        "to_name"     => '',
        'template_id' => 123456,                  // KO : 0 in the response
    );
    $content         = array(
        "text"         => "dunno what to use here",
        "url"          => 'dunno what to use here',
        "archive"      => "dunno what to use here",
    );
    $response = $campaignService->create('regular', $options, $content);
    dpm($response);

    return '';
}
```